# Logging via FileAppender

Tags: log4net, fileappender

here is an easy question coming:

i am trying to use log4net to log the infos on a file.  i wrote
 < file value="log-file.txt" /> into my appender tag in app.config. and now wondering where the log-file.txt is positioned and whether it is created automatically or i should create it by myself.

i am using c# - wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in the Debug\Bin or Release\Bin folder.
if its not there, try specifying full path.

Answer (score 2):

The file will automatically be created if it doesn't exist. 
It may require that the application has write permission to the folder where the logfile is placed. 
As Orentet mentions this is normally the bin folder.